# Datepicker and GestureControl Question - Swift

Tags: swift, datepicker, nsdate

I currently have a datepicker. Essentially, what I would like to do is if you swipe left the date goes back one day Ie (2nd Jan to 1st Jan) or swipe right goes forward one day Ie (2nd Jan to 3rd Jan). I have successfully implemented a way to do this using the current date but the issue is it stops there as it takes the current date data. Basically, this will not let me continuously go back or forth in days as it takes the current date. I would like to make it go back or forth 1 day endlessly. How could I improve my code? Thank you in advance.

ViewController:

```
 @IBOutlet weak var userDate: UITextField!
    private var datePicker: UIDatePicker?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        datePicker = UIDatePicker()
        datePicker?.datePickerMode = .date
        datePicker?.addTarget(self, action: #selector(Test.dateChanged(datePicker:)), for: .valueChanged)

        userDate.inputView = datePicker
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEEE, MMM d, yyyy"
        let todayDate = dateFormatter.string(from: Date.init())
        self.userDate.text = todayDate
        
        let swipeLeft = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.handleGesture(gesture:)))
            swipeLeft.direction = .left
            self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeLeft)

        let swipeRight = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.handleGesture(gesture:)))
            swipeRight.direction = .right
            self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeRight)

    }
    
    @objc func handleGesture(gesture: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) -> Void {
        
        if gesture.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizer.Direction.right {
               print("Swipe Right")
              view.backgroundColor = .black
               Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: -1, to: datePicker.date)! // WHAT NEEDS TO BE CHANGED IN ORDER FOR IT TO CONTINUOSLY ALLOW GOING BACK THE DATES
        }
        else if gesture.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizer.Direction.left {
               print("Swipe Left")
                view.backgroundColor = .yellow
               Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: datePicker.date)! // WHAT NEEDS TO BE CHANGED IN ORDER FOR IT TO CONTINUOSLY ALLOW GOING FORWARD THE DATES
           }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that when you put a value in the userDate.text field you pass the day and time of that moment and you never update it. Your code needs to change as follows.

```
private var daysDifference = 0 // The days difference from the now date. Negative numbers go for previous dates and positives for future dates.

override func viewDidLoad() {
    // As is
}

@objc func handleGesture(gesture: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) -> Void {
    
    if gesture.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizer.Direction.right {
           print("Swipe Right")
          view.backgroundColor = .black
          self.daysDifference = self.daysDifference - 1 // Update daysDifference for one day before
    } else if gesture.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizer.Direction.left {
           print("Swipe Left")
           view.backgroundColor = .yellow
           self.daysDifference = self.daysDifference + 1 // Update daysDifference for one day after
    }
    self.userDate.text = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: self.daysDifference, to: datePicker.date)!
}
```